# Caliburn.micro - notifying a viewmodel on property change in another viewmodel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, viewmodel, caliburn.micro

I have a program that connects to a server and sends commands to it.
in my program I have 2 windows, one of them is a toolbar with a textbox that shows current status (we'll call that "mainviewmodel") and the other is a login window which receives username and password and logs me into the server (we'll call that "loginviewmodel")

now, in order for the mainviewmodel to know the loginviewmodel I use this:

```
[Import]
Private LoginViewModel loginViewModel;
```

lunch the login window from the mainviewmodel I have the following function:

```
public void Login()
{
    if (!loginViewModel.CanInvokeLogin)
        return;
    if (loginViewModel.IsActive)
    {
        loginViewModel.Focus();
    }
else
    {
        windowManager.ShowWindow(loginViewModel);
    }
}
```

as you can see - I have in loginviewmodel a property named CanInvokeLogin which indicates if login is in progress or not.

on mainviewmodel I have a property that shows me current client status (binded to the view's textbox)

```
public string TextboxDescription
{
    get
    {
        switch (AvailabilityStatus.Type)
        {
            case AvailabilityStatusType.READY:
                return ("Ready");
            case AvailabilityStatusType.BREAK:
                return (AvailabilityStatus.Reason);
            case AvailabilityStatusType.DISCONNECTED:
                if (!loginViewModel.CanInvokeLogin)
                {
                    return ("Conencting");
                }
                return ("connected");
            default:
                return ("Please wait...");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is - the status would not be updated on the view unless

```
NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => TextboxDescription);
```

is being called, so I need to call it whenever

```
NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => CanInvokeLogin);
```

is being called, but that happens on a different viewmodel.

so, how can I notify the mainviewmodel that caninvokelogin have been changed?
I know I could use eventAggregator and send a message from one viewmodel to another, but it sounds like killing a fly with a cannon and I bet there's a simpler way,

any suggestions?

Comment: I would defiantly use an eventaggregator in this scenario

Comment: Why if there is a reference to the view model? Just use plain old .NET events.

Comment: Any reason for the aggregator rather than signing up to the events like suggested?, eran?

Comment: The Event Aggregator is a nice tool if you are broadcasting something app wide... I would perhaps use the Event Aggregator when a user logged out of the app for example, or perhaps when they login if many other classes around the system needed to react to such events. In the example you have given though, plain old events are a nice solution... like you said... don't kill a fly with a cannon.

Comment: In the end I did switch to using eventaggregator - using events caused my program to crawl into a halt, suddenly with each disconnect&connect on the user behalf more and more propertychange events have been sent, it may be due to something I wrote badly so I'm still testing it, but it seems that using caliburn messages is superior to using events, in this case anyway :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Handle The Property Changed Event**

The PropertyChanged event is simply an event so there is nothing stopping you from listening to that event from another view model if that is what you need.

```
this.loginViewModel.PropertyChanged += this.OnLoginPropertyChanged;
```

The event handler method would look something like this...

```
private void OnLoginPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == "TextboxDescription") {
        // Do something.
    }
}
```

**Raise StatusChanged Events:**

To be honest if I was implementing this myself I would simply be firing events from the LoginViewModel when the status changed and then handling those events instead, seems like a cleaner solution to this.

```
this.loginViewModel.StatusChanged += this.OnLoginStatusChanged;

private void OnLoginStatusChanged(object sender, LoginStatusChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Do something.
    switch (e.StatusType)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

I would have custom event args like so...

```
public class LoginStatusChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
     public AvailabilityStatusType StatusType { get; set; }
}
```

Just fire this event when the status changes and listeners can handle that.

**Event Aggregator:**

You could also use the event aggregator however unless you have lots of disconnected classes that need to listen to this I would probably feel it was overkill.

```
this.eventAggregator.Publish(new LoginStatusChangedMessage(AvailabilityStatusType.Disconnected));
```

Comment: Can't edit and missed the rest of the answer :) I don't like the publishing events idea as you're not supposed to login more than once (or if for some reason you're bored/QA and decides to login&logout plenty of times), the code I published is only what is needed, the rest is implemented more or less as you suggested.